# html - Bootstrap 3 collapse button appears but no effect when clicked?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make it so that when I click my collapse button, the two labels will appear, but it's not happening even though the data-target and id (colnav) of the navbar are same.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#colnav">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
          </button>

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <%= image_tag("iinfo.png", :alt => "INFOMAN") %>
          </a>
        </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="colnav">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
              <li class="color-me">
                <a href="#" style="color:red">
                  Contact Us
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <% if current_user %>
                <%= link_to 'Logout', session_path("new") , method: "delete"%>
                <% end %>
              </li>
            </ul> 
      </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->

    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: witch bootstrap version you are using?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 4

Comment: Sorry Urvi_204, I meant bootstrap 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap requires jQuery for its effects. If you're requiring bootstrap via its CDN, you need to ensure that jquery is loaded in your `application.html.erb`. See [this official template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#template).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, if you're requiring bootstrap through the bootstrap gem, then you need to ensure that `gem 'jquery-rails'` is in your gemfile, and your `application.js` manifest file requires jquery.

See [the gem documentation](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) for correct installation details.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually happens when you haven't linked your `bootstrap.min.js` file correctly.